# If session$sendCustomMessage has maximal length? And how to change it?

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I have a relatively big object that should be sent to UI from the server. And I use session$sendCustomMessage to transfer the data. The code is like this:

```
session$sendCustomMessage('attribution_list',result)
```

However, in the UI page, I find the received object is not complete. It looks like to be truncated in certain length.
I wonder if there is a parameter to set this length and how to do it? In addition, is there other approach to transfer big data from server to ui?
The total length of the characters is 389702

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is precise, but in order for us to understand and solve it, 
it is necessary that you provide some sample data. There are several ways to provide data, 
probably adding the output of `dput(<yourData>)` or `dput(head(<yourData>))` to your question is sufficient. 
Avoid adding code or alphanumeric output as images. Consider how to make a good example: 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example
and see how you can change your question accordingly.

Comment: I think by default the max size is set to 5Mb `shiny.maxRequestSize` how big is the object?

Comment: The json string has 39702 characters. And I think it's not shiny.maxRestSize. Because I have set this parameter by options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 1000*1024^2) before.

Comment: Please post reporducible example